# How to add if statement in knex.select()?

Tags: sql, postgresql, knex.js

I have  code like this

```
const attr = req.query.attr
knex.select(knex.raw('foo_name as name'))
```

what I want is somehow select that column if it meets condition of attr and if does not then do select nothing.
Something like:

```
knex.select(if(attr == foo){knex.raw()})
```

Comment: Why can't you use an `if/else` to define two different `knex.select(knex.raw())` calls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can assign the selection on other variable and then pass it to `kenx.select`.

```
const selection = attr == foo ? knex.raw('bla') : knex.raw('');
await knex.select(selection);
```

Comment: I did something similar! Good answer.